# Efficient ways to reuse a Java compiler's backend for a new JVM language

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I'm writing a language targeted at the JVM, and I'm currently putting the
compiler together. It becomes apparent to me that, logically, my new language
has many of the same needs as Java when it comes to creating the bytecode. Just
to give a few examples:

- Find out what a dot-separated sequence of identifiers refers to: a.b.c could
  refer to local variable a, field a, class a or class a.b
- Convert primitive types for arithmetic operations: for intVar*doubleVar,
  intVar has to be cast to double
- Find the matching method for a set of parameters: With proper inheritance and
  the same primitive casting as above
- on a related note, autoboxing
- generic type checking, e.g. whether `List<X<? super Y>> l = new List<X<Z>>();`
  is compatible

There's probably much more, and I somehow don't want to reinvent these wheels
(making a new language, of course I'm reinventing *some* wheels already...), so
I wondered what would be the best ways to reuse (parts of) an existing Java
compiler, passing it the pieces of the AST it needs to figure out the above.

I do already have lexer and parser (ANTLR) in place, so I'm really looking for
advice on what compilers are out there that would make it relatively easy for
me to work with them (for example, I have looked a little into ECJ, but if
someone told me that it's not capable of what I want or another compiler would
be easier to use that would be great).

to sum it up with a definite question: Which Java compilers out there have an
easily accessible backend that is suiteable to be used with a frontend for a
non-Java JVM language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two extensible compiler backend that I heard of while reading academic papers:

- [polyglot extensible compiler framewok](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Projects/polyglot/)
- [JastAddJ](http://jastadd.org/web/jastaddj/)

For domain-specific language engineering, I would suggest

- [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) and for instance [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/), a variation of Java

These projects seem mature. I never had a close look to them, but I really would like to ;)

Comment: I think this hits exactly what I'm looking for. that their grammars aren't ANTLR based can't be helped, I guess. It will give me a peek into LL vs LR parsing in the process.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being a little obtuse, my answer is Scala.

Scala is a JVM-based language which has, as of the latest release, [a macro system](http://scalamacros.org). Macros (when they're more powerful than the ones associated with C) are a technique for building domain-specific languages on top of existing languages, without having to start from scratch. A macro system lets you write code in the existing language, enhanced by new constructs, and will compile the new constructs down into the base language.

If you want to build straight off of Java, it might be worth considering the [Java Syntax Extender](http://jse.sourceforge.net/), but JSE is not extensively used, and may be pretty rough. (There may, in fact, be more mature Java macro systems I haven't heard of.)

Comment: thanks for your input! I have used Scala a few times, but It's not what I'm looking for here. Academically, just wanting to try another way is enough a reason for me. technically, I think there are some feature I wouldn't get with Scala, e.g. closures accessing local variables from the enclosing method.
I will look into JSE and try it out though!